# Joomla 404 component not found (custom component)

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, xml

I am trying to create a custom component in my Joomla backend, so I created this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="3.8.1" method="upgrade">
<name>administratie</name>
<creationDate>2019-04-09</creationDate>
<author>Twan</author>
<authorEmail>you@example.com</authorEmail>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<description>Administratie dashboard</description>
<administration>
<menu>administratie</menu>

<files folder="components/com_administratie/admin">
<file>administratie.php</file>
</files>
</administration>
</extension>
```

And installed it, which worked, the `administratie` link is added in my components drop down, except when I click on it, the page shows a `404 component not found` error.

Maybe I wrote something wrong in my xml file? I can't find what it is. This is my folder structure:

```
administrator
-components
--com_administratie
---admin
---administratie.xml
----administratie.php (this file has a simple echo in it)
```

I already tried refreshing the cache but I keep getting the same error.

I am on Joomla version: `Joomla! 3.8.1 Stable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it is ambiguous whether your entry file is inside the admin subfolder or not.  It should be in the com_administratie folder if it isn't.  Also your xml files declaration looks odd:

```
<files folder="components/com_administratie/admin">
<file>administratie.php</file>
</files>
```

The folder attribute should just be site or admin.  While sub folders can be included as folder elements.  So something like the following:

```
<files folder="admin">
  <filename>administratie.php</filename>
  <folder>admin</folder>
</files>
```

If you're only using discovery to install then the file declarations don't matter as much.  In any case, the component will look at

```
/administrator/components/com_administratie/administratie.php
```

as the default entry file without much prompting.

Comment: Thank you,this worked. I followed a tutorial which said I had to add the .php file in a subfolder, when I moved it one level up the component showed up in my backend!

Comment: cool. glad to help.